# Newer version of python cannot find module pygame

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I was finally able to get python 3.9.0 installed(was using 3.4.2) on my raspberry pi, however I cannot use pygame now stating "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pygame'. I know where pygame is located, but I have no idea how to get python 3.9.0 to see where it is to read it.

Comment: you need to install it with something like `python3.9 -m pip install pygame`

Comment: If I do python -m pip install pygame I get a lot of errors.

Comment: Do a `python -V` to make sure you're getting the version you think you are.  It's tricky to have multiple versions.

Comment: I get python 3.9.0.

Comment: may you install did not go as well as you think... what happens if you do `python -m pip --version`? How did you install Python? From source? From a package manager?

Comment: I would not be surprised. I actually used this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R9MI41ARN8&t=182s tutorial as I have never used terminal to install python before. When I run python -m pip --version it get pip 20.2.3 from and then the location.

Comment: is it just pygame you are having trouble installing or other packages as well? also the error messages you get when you attempt the install could be helpful

Comment: I haven't tried to install any other packages, and there is no error message when I install it. It states its already installed, but when I call it I get NoModuleFound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-install all of your packages when you upgrade to a new major version of Python.  You'll need to `pip3 install xxxx` again.

Comment: I guess I should have specified I already tried pip3 install pygame and it did not work. It says Requirement already satisfied and then gives the location of where pygame is.